# HQL: Finding object where child objects include specific attribute values

Tags: java, sql, hql

This is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838806/sql-query-one-table-based-on-join-on-another-table-that-has-multiple-matches) question.

Instead of SQL, how would I do the same using HQL? (i.e. find all dogs that have both the colors of black and white but could have other colors)

Let's say my entity classes look like this:

```
public class Dog {
    private Long id;
    private Set<DogColor> colors;
    private String name;
    private String size;

    ...
}

public class DogColor {
    private Long id;
    private String color;

    ...
}
```

Then I want my HQL to look a little something like this:

```
from dog where dog.colors contains ("black", "white")
```

Obviously this is just pseudo-code since dog.colors is an object and not the color strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select d from dog d join d.colors o where o.color in ("black","white")
```

Of course you need to have the right mapping set up

Comment: Thanks! using the child of the parent in the join and using 'where' instead of 'on' is where I went wrong.